# Jobs behind schedule in Ultimate Cron

Tags: cron

I almost always have over 30 jobs behind schedule in Ultimate Cron, and I'm trying to understand why that is, and how I can fix that.

I am using Ultimate Cron 2.x, with Background Process.

A good portion of my jobs say something like, "8 months behind schedule" and the most recent one is 3 weeks behind schedule.

Why do my cron jobs keep running behind schedule? How do I fix this? Is this a configuration error that I caused in Ultimate Cron? Or would this be due to a bug?

EDIT: I'm also sometimes getting an error that says:

"Could not get lock for job system_cron"

And I also found this:

"UltimateCronBackgroundProcessLegacyLauncher::poormanLauncher" under locked job.

Comment: I think, there is also a similar problems in ultimate cron issue queue. here is the link https://www.drupal.org/node/2216433 , I hope It would give answer to your questions

Comment: The difference there is that the launcher is set to serial. Mine is background process.

Comment: Did you verify the jobs run to completion? or might some cron jobs never complete and hang the next. The background jobs are not running in seperate processes as far as i can see.